# Unhandled exception when overloading << operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the << operator for a New Integer class that detects overflow of operations and below are my parts of codes:

```
    class NewInteger{
                private: 
                int num;

                public: 
                NewInteger();
                NewInteger(int);
                friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream& out, const NewInteger& rhs);
                NewInteger operator+ (NewInteger);

                .../ many other member functions/
            }
```

Implementations are:

```
    NewInteger NewInteger::operator+(NewInteger n)
{
    int a = this->getValue();
    int b = n.getValue();
    if (a > 0 && b > max - a) {
        throw std::exception();
        std::cout << "studpid" << std::endl;
    }
    if (a < 0 && b < min - a) {
        throw std::exception();
    }

    return NewInteger(a + b);
}
  std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const NewInteger& rhs)
    {
        out << rhs;
        return out;
    }
```

In the main.cpp, I try to test the code by running:

```
    NewInteger n7(4);
    NewInteger n8(5);
    std::cout << n7.operator+(n8) << std::endl;
```

The code builds fine and when I run it on Visual Studio 2015, it causes the program to close without giving a fatal error. So when I debug the code, it gives me: `

```
Exception thrown at 0x00C43B49 in NewInteger.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00192F90)
```

and the break point appears right at the implementation of operator<<. But I cannot figure out what exception I should try to catch at the implementation.

Can somebody please tell me what is the cause of this?

Comment: Wait... you *intended* for an infinite recursive `operator <<`? Because that is *exactly* what you coded.

Comment: This "exception" is not a C++ exception and you cannot catch it with `catch`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const NewInteger& rhs)
{
    out << rhs;
    return out;
}
```

The first line calls `operator<<` on `out` and `rhs` -- which is the function you're defining.  You have infinite recursion.

Comment: that makes sense. What should I replace it with? A template code was written exactly like this in a sample code provided form our class.

Comment: I'd go with something like `out << rhs.num;`